# PrimeFaces selectManyCheckbox doesn't generate ui classes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Other elements in the project work, like p:tree, p:calendar; but selectManyCheckbox doesn't. The theme is in place, all configured like in the specs.

It is getting frustrating, any thoughts? Much appreciated!

EDIT:
I use version 3.2

This is the output html

```
<fieldset>  <label><span class="filter-criteria-label">Catégories           principales: </span></label>    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="dtUserList:selectRoles">      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">             <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="CLIENT"
                name="dtUserList:selectRoles" id="dtUserList:selectRoles:0"><label
                for="dtUserList:selectRoles:0">Grand public</label><input
                type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="REFERRANT_ENTREPRISE"
                name="dtUserList:selectRoles" id="dtUserList:selectRoles:1"><label
                for="dtUserList:selectRoles:1">Référent</label><input
                type="checkbox" value="CLIENT_ENTREPRISE"
                name="dtUserList:selectRoles" id="dtUserList:selectRoles:2"><label
                for="dtUserList:selectRoles:2">Entreprise</label><input
                type="checkbox" value="EXPLOITANT" name="dtUserList:selectRoles"
                id="dtUserList:selectRoles:3"><label
                for="dtUserList:selectRoles:3">Exploitant</label><input
                type="checkbox" value="PRESTATAIRE"
                name="dtUserList:selectRoles" id="dtUserList:selectRoles:4"><label
                for="dtUserList:selectRoles:4">Prestataire</label><input
                type="checkbox" value="CALL_CENTER"
                name="dtUserList:selectRoles" id="dtUserList:selectRoles:5"><label
                for="dtUserList:selectRoles:5">Callcenter</label><input
                type="checkbox" value="REGISSEUR" name="dtUserList:selectRoles"
                id="dtUserList:selectRoles:6"><label
                for="dtUserList:selectRoles:6">Regisseur</label>        </fieldset>     </div> </fieldset>
```

This is how it should look (taken from PF showcase):

```
<table class="ui-selectmanycheckbox ui-widget" id="form:horizontal">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1" name="form:horizontal"
                            id="form:horizontal:0">
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span>
                    </div>
                </div></td>
            <td><label for="form:horizontal:0">Option 1</label></td>
            <td><div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2" name="form:horizontal"
                            id="form:horizontal:1">
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span>
                    </div>
                </div></td>
            <td><label for="form:horizontal:1">Option 2</label></td>
            <td><div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3" name="form:horizontal"
                            id="form:horizontal:2">
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span>
                    </div>
                </div></td>
            <td><label for="form:horizontal:2">Option 3</label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your classpath clean and crisp? (i.e. no duplicated different versioned PF libraries). Have you registered any custom `<renderer>` in `faces-config.xml` which could possibly override the PF one? Anyway, putting a debug breakpoint in component's `encodeAll()` and advancing from there should give insight as to what's happening under the covers.

Comment: I had "<application><default-render-kit-id>PRIMEFACES_MOBILE</default-render-kit-id></application>" in my faces-config.xml.

Thank you kind sir, thank you!! :) Please post your comment as an answer and i'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen when you're using the wrong renderer for the component. This can in turn have several causes:

1. The runtime classpath is polluted with multiple different versioned PrimeFaces libraries. The renderer of the one version may not match the component in the other version.
2. A custom renderer has been registered through `<render-kit>` in `faces-config.xml`.
3. A different render kit has been registered through `<default-render-kit-id>` or `<render-kit-factory>` in `faces-config.xml`.